# How to get the digits of a number without converting it to a string/ char array?

Tags: c++

How do I get what the digits of a number are in C++ without converting it to strings or character arrays?

Comment: Do u want to get number of digits or all the digits in that number in separate variables or integer array?

Comment: What do you mean?  
Do you want to count the number of digits?  
Do you want to extract the 5th digit from a number?

Comment: Number of what type? Is it integer or double?

Comment: I wanted a way to get all the individual digits into something like an array.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The following prints the digits in order of ascending significance (i.e. units, then tens, etc.):

```
do {
    int digit = n % 10;
    putchar('0' + digit);
    n /= 10;
} while (n > 0);
```

Comment: if( n == 0 ) no digits are printed.

Comment: Do you expect anything when n == 0? I would expect that to be an invalid input thus undefined behavior or an assert.

Comment: Not worthy of a downvote. This is an illustration, not production-ready code.

Comment: And n == 0 *is* a valid input, in my view - the answer is a single digit, '0'.

Comment: My previous comment was at @xtolf. I think the code was fine.

Comment: You hardly need printf, BTW.  '0' + digit works in ASCII/Unicode.  You realize you have simply re-implemented printf %d, right?  sprintf %d the original number into a buffer, then reverse the buffer.  Put in \n between the digits if you want.  Note that sprintf returns the number of characters printed.

Answer (score 20):

What about `floor(log(number))+1`?

With *n* digits and using base *b* you can express any number up to `pow(b,n)-1`. So to get the number of digits of a number *x* in base *b* you can use the inverse function of exponentiation: base-b logarithm. To deal with non-integer results you can use the `floor()+1` trick.

PS: This works for integers, not for numbers with decimals (in that case you should know what's the precision of the type you are using).

Comment: After two years, I still don't get why this answer wasn't good as the others.

Comment: You can't use `ceil(log(x))` instead of `floor(log(x))+1` as `ceil` returns wrong values when `log(x) % 1 == 0`(e.g. when `x = 100` you expect to get _3_ (using `floor+1`) instead of _2_ (using just `ceil`).

Comment: @tunnuz: This was no good answer as this gave the number of digits and not the digits of a number as requested.

Comment: @Nippey: what's the differente between "number of digits" and "digits of a number"?

Comment: Take the number `123321` as example. The `number of digits` is `6`. The digits of this number are `1`,`2`,`3`,`3`,`2` and `1`.

Answer (score 15):

Since everybody is chiming in without knowing the question.
Here is my attempt at futility:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int D> int getDigit(int val)       {return getDigit<D-1>(val/10);}
template<>      int getDigit<1>(int val)    {return val % 10;}

int main()
{
    std::cout << getDigit<5>(1234567) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Although the runtime complexity is O( sizeof(int)^2 ) when calculating all digits.  Hmm.... And how do you know at what digit to start?

Comment: Technically the runtime complexity is O(1) because the code will not change for different input values. Note Big O notation is a measure of how runtime scales in relation to input arguments.

Comment: It seems like you pretty much got what i was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: If I do `qDebug() << getDigit<0>(32);`, I get: `fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex` with MSVC2015. I'm assuming the template parameter determines the index of the digit?

Comment: @Mitch: The above works for `n >= 1` There is no specialization for zero or negative numbers

Answer (score 13):

I have seen many answers, but they **all** forgot to use `do {...} while()` loop, which is actually the canonical way to solve this problem and handle `0` properly.

My solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397737/how-to-get-the-digits-of-a-number-without-converting-it-to-a-string-char-array/1397767#1397767) one by [Naveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/39742/naveen).

```
int n = 0;
std::cin>>n;

std::deque<int> digits;
n = abs(n);
do {
    digits.push_front( n % 10);
    n /= 10;
} while (n>0);
```

Answer (score 8):

You want to some thing like this?

```
 int n = 0;
    std::cin>>n;

    std::deque<int> digits;
    if(n == 0)
    {
        digits.push_front(0);
        return 0;
    }

    n = abs(n);
    while(n > 0)
    {
        digits.push_front( n % 10);
        n = n /10;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand how this works. Would need to read up on std containers.

Comment: Using std containers is a waste here. Wasting CPU resources doing unnecessary heap operations

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
int* GetDigits(int num, int * array, int len) {
  for (int i = 0; i < len && num != 0; i++) {
    array[i] = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
  }
}
```

The mod 10's will get you the digits.  The div 10s will advance the number.

Comment: You might not have `len` - it's better to terminate when `num` gets to 0.

Comment: Good point.  Need len to make sure we don't over-run the array.  Added a check for num being 0 though.

Comment: This can be easily refactored to generate digits for any base. For now it generates digits only for base 10...

Answer (score 4):

Integer version is trivial:

```
int fiGetDigit(const int n, const int k)
{//Get K-th Digit from a Number (zero-based index)
    switch(k)
    {
        case 0:return n%10;
        case 1:return n/10%10;
        case 2:return n/100%10;
        case 3:return n/1000%10;
        case 4:return n/10000%10;
        case 5:return n/100000%10;
        case 6:return n/1000000%10;
        case 7:return n/10000000%10;
        case 8:return n/100000000%10;
        case 9:return n/1000000000%10;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

simple recursion:

```
#include <iostream>

// 0-based index pos
int getDigit (const long number, int pos) 
{
    return (pos == 0) ? number % 10 : getDigit (number/10, --pos);
}

int main (void) {
    std::cout << getDigit (1234567, 4) << "\n";    
}
```

Comment: Brilliantly simple and concise

Answer (score 3):

Those solutions are all recursive or iterative.  Might a more direct approach be a little more efficient?

Left-to-right:

```
int getDigit(int from, int index)
{
   return (from / (int)pow(10, floor(log10(from)) - index)) % 10;
}
```

Right-to-left:

```
int getDigit(int from, int index)
{
   return (from / pow(10, index)) % 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First digit (least significant) = num % 10, second digit = floor(num/10)%10, 3rd digit = floor(num/100)%10. etc

Comment: Nice and general solution.  Going through the floating point `floor` function doesn't make much sense, though.  Do take a look at Martin's solution, too!

Comment: Well... I wouldn't actually use floor() but I included that in case the OP was using floats or whatever... just to make it explicit. If he's using int's, then no problem, it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use the log 10 of a number. It returns the total digits of the number - 1. It could be fixed by using converting the number to an int.

```cpp
int(log10(number)) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence of mod 10 and div 10 operations (whatever the syntax is in C++) to assign the 
digits one at a time to other variables.

In pseudocode

```
lsd = number mod 10
number = number div 10
next lsd = number mod 10
number = number div 10
```

etc...

painful! ... but no strings or character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Not as cool as Martin York's answer, but addressing just an arbitrary a problem:

You can print a positive integer greater than zero rather simply with recursion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print(int x)
{
    if (x>0) {
        print(x/10);
        putchar(x%10 + '0');
    }
}
```

This will print out the least significant digit last.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago, in response to the above questions I would write the following code:

```
int i2a_old(int n, char *s)
{
    char d,*e=s;//init begin pointer
    do{*e++='0'+n%10;}while(n/=10);//extract digits
    *e--=0;//set end of str_number
    int digits=e-s;//calc number of digits
    while(s<e)d=*s,*s++=*e,*e--=d;//reverse digits of the number
    return digits;//return number of digits
}
```

I think that the function printf(...) does something like that.

Now I will write this:

```
int i2a_new(int n, char *s)
{
    int digits=n<100000?n<100?n<10?1:2:n<1000?3:n<10000?4:5:n<10000000?n<1000000?6:7:n<100000000?8:n<1000000000?9:10;
    char *e=&s[digits];//init end pointer
    *e=0;//set end of str_number
    do{*--e='0'+n%10;}while(n/=10);//extract digits
    return digits;//return number of digits
}
```

**Advantages:**
  lookup table indipendent; 
  C,C++,Java,JavaScript,PHP compatible;
  get number of digits, `min comparisons: 3`;
  get number of digits, `max comparisons: 4`;
  fast code;
  a comparison is very simple and fast:  `cmp reg, immediate_data`  -->  1 CPU clock.

Comment: Your code is broken. It accepts negative numbers but doesn't work with them, and makes assumptions about the size of `int`

Answer (score 0):

Get all the individual digits into something like an array - two variants:

```
int i2array_BigEndian(int n, char a[11])
{//storing the most significant digit first
    int digits=//obtain the number of digits with 3 or 4 comparisons
    n<100000?n<100?n<10?1:2:n<1000?3:n<10000?4:5:n<10000000?n<1000000?6:7:n<100000000?8:n<1000000000?9:10;
    a+=digits;//init end pointer
    do{*--a=n%10;}while(n/=10);//extract digits
    return digits;//return number of digits
}

int i2array_LittleEndian(int n, char a[11])
{//storing the least significant digit first
    char *p=&a[0];//init running pointer
    do{*p++=n%10;}while(n/=10);//extract digits
    return p-a;//return number of digits
}
```